# requestmap in spring mvc

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i want to create a form in which user can set name, age, birthday and department which is another object..
in jsp i already have the form with the inputs of name, age and birthday. For department i already create the select/option tag with the results from hibernate/db.
The problem is when i sumbit and post the the mployee i have a lot of erros

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/new" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveEmployee(@Valid @ModelAttribute Employee employee,
        @PathVariable("department") int department, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model) {
```

jsp file

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="department">
            <c:forEach var="dep" items="${departments}">
                <option value="${dep.id}">${dep.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

i want to pass with post the employee info with department id to create the employee

Comment: *"(...) I have a lot of errors"*? Surely you can't be thinking that this is enough information?

Comment: i dont push any error because i dont have any clue how can i do it.... i am trying a lot of things. Until now i have this error

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Comment: also i changed my jsp file with
<td><label for="departments">Department: </label> </td>
    <td>
    <form:select path="departments" id="departments">
     <form:options items="${departments}"></form:options>
    </form:select>
    </td>

Comment: You have the cause right there in your stack strace: `ConstraintViolationException`, its documentation should be your first stop in trying to figure out the reason. None of the code you included is relevant as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

Your BindingResult parameter needs to go directly after your Employee parameter.

Comment: yes i agree with you but i do not have any clue how i can do this.... i thry almost everything that i found on internet....